# Issue with Tiptip plugin in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, tooltip

We are using Jquery tip tip plugin of jquery for showing tool tips

We have tree(using Jstree- lazy loading). the tree nodes will be opened only on clicking an expand all button. So the tree contents are loaded dynamically.

To show tool tip, we have used the tiptip

```
    $('a[title]').live('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).tipTip(); 
    $(this).trigger('mouseenter'); 
});
```

But in IE, it is showing the IE tooltip(default) using the title attribute and with the Tip Tip plugin also. We dont need the IE default tooltip. Please help in how to avoid this

Regards
Hari

Comment: I have never used this plugin however reading on the website it says that this plugin is activated by default with a 'hover' event. Maybe it is not working as it should because you are calling the plugin from within a 'mouseover' event? Just an idea...

Comment: I tried with hover, but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

try to change the attribute.. now you use the attribute title..try to change with a custom one.. try to change the title attribute with , for example... "tiptip" attribute..